# How to add timer element to Google Forms App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a friend I am collaborating with to help write an application specially designed for educators. It is built on Google Forms + Apps Script, which believe it or not, is really impressive. However, he asked a question I cannot answer. On certain forms, he would like to have a visual element for a timer with a start and stop button. Does anybody know if that is even possible, and if so, then how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ability to affect the content of a Google Form is limited to the items that make up the extent of the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/).

Unfortunately that does not include a Timer element.

This would first need to be supported by the Forms product, before it could be manipulated by Google Apps Script. The topic has been brought up in the [Google Docs Support Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/docs/category$3Aforms$20timer) many times. Hopefully it gets attention from Google.

As an alternative, you could create your own HTML form with a timer widget.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that.